# How do I copy selected rows in excel?

Tags: excel

I have combined some sheets now I want to copy selected rows. What I did is held ctrl key and then selected all the 4 rows I wanted but how do I select these rows more quickly?

[image]

Edit: **Explaining what I am trying to do.**

http://results.eci.gov.in/pc/en/constituencywise/ConstituencywiseU011.htm
This is the website of election commission of India. I want to do some analysis on this data but before that, I am sorting data. What I have done so far is that I open this website repeatedly and there are 28 states each state has some number of constituencies. The total number of constituencies is 543, that means I have to click 543 times at least. I press ctr+A and paste it on a sheet. What I want are the top 4 candidates. I first apply filter sort them largest to smallest then copy top 4 candidates and copy them paste them in my main sheet. I am finding a quick and fast way to solve this problem. The one I am doing is very time-consuming. Can anyone suggest me some ideas?

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Down

Comment: @GalAbra Sir it selects whole column

Comment: What do you mean, select it more quickly? Holding down `CTRL` isn't fast enough? What is your goal and how do you expect to select specific rows even quicker?

Comment: Your question wasn't clear before adding the pictures. I can't think of a feature that'll allow such specific behavior

Comment: @GalAbra It doesn't allow me to insert picture before.

Comment: @JvdV Data is big. Pressing ctrl and dragging mouse is time-consuming. If there is no alternative then ofcourse I have to do this procedure.But sir can you suggest some quick version of selecting four candidates http://results.eci.gov.in/pc/en/constituencywise/ConstituencywiseS281.htm?ac=1. Who received more votes. I have to first select whole data from a website then I have to apply a filter for largest to smallest then I have to select 4 top candidates. Can you give me some tips on how to clean this date in some better manner. Pardon my english .

Comment: If it is too time consuming you can look into VBA selecting rows for you, but you need some kind of rule on what bases these rows are selected. Also, if your goal is to copy/paste them, selecting rows isn't even necessary through VBA.

Comment: @JvdV I edited my comment please look again.

Comment: So after each textstring of `TOTAL` in column `K` you are selecting the first four values to be copied over. Then that's your bases to start working on in VBA. Search for keywords like `FindNext`, `Offset` and `Transpose`. There are plenty examples around.

Comment: @JvdV I have not studied VBA yet this is my first time on excel. Can you help me with that code sir ?

Comment: @JvdV Do you have team viewer ? Can you access my pc and tell me how to do things please.

Comment: I'm not here to write you a piece of code from scratch I'm afraid. But like the answer below, there can also be formulas used to determine the rows you want selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding another column where you put a value (eg. 1) against all rows you want to copy, filtering based on that column and copying and pasting.

Comment: Don't you think it will be as time-consuming as pressing ctrl and selecting rows I want to copy.

Comment: A formula would help you out doing this. So it's not a bad suggestion. In `P3` put this formula: `=IFERROR(OR(OFFSET(K3,-1,0)="TOTAL",OFFSET(K3,-2,0)="TOTAL",OFFSET(K3,-3,0)="TOTAL",OFFSET(K3,-4,0)="TOTAL"),TRUE)` and drag down.

Comment: Do you have criteria which can be used to determine which rows to copy?

Comment: @JvdV It was very helpful thanks but can you see my edited question. I am trying to find out false it won't find. I want to delete rows that contain false.

Comment: Why not applying a filter like @Pan suggested?